# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255] latex-studio

Tags: pdftex, luatex, latex-workshop

I'm currently writing an important paper. I'm trying out LaTeX for the first Time and I keep encountering this issue seemingly random:

TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]

Sometimes, if I'm simply trying to make an nusorted list, or if I'm just adding the \thanks tag to \author.
I've looked around for quite some time to find an answer, but every answer i could find was just a workaround for a specific scenario. Can somebody tell my, what's causing this issue? It keeps occuring again and again in different places and to always find a workaround is just not cutting it :D

I'm using VS Code with the LaTeX Workshop extension and Tex Live. I also tried it out in Texmaker with the same result.
I also tried to compile with lualatex and a few others, because that was the only thing I was able to find.

This is the first time I've encountered this Problem, just Copy-Pasting the Tutorial from Overleaf.
This example here is working

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{cool document}
\author{Mr. Nobody}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

As soon as i was adding the \thanks tag the code no longer compiled and instead output following error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{cool document}
\author{Mr. Nobody \thanks{My mom}}
 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Error message in VS Code:

```
Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (850,850)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'test.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'test.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'test.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'test.log' and/or above output for details

C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=d:/PathToFile
```

Error message in Texmaker:

```
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `TS1' unknown.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.54 ...ontFamily{TS1}{cmr}{\hyphenchar\font\m@ne}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\UseTextSymbol #1#2->\hmode@start@before@group {
\def \@wrong@font@char {\Me...
l.8 \maketitle
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
461 strings out of 474373
9205 string characters out of 2753366
1923078 words of memory out of 5000000
22646 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
559914 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
253i,11n,486p,137b,2657s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: No issues here. Can you provide the contents of the actual log file, not the filtered stuff that the editors provide. Additionaly does it help to delete the aux file first?

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme \`TS1' unknown.`  TS1 encoding is part of the core latex release. You have a broken latex installation but it is hard to see why. What tex distribution are you using? (it looks like windows texlive 2023 from your log fragment) ?

Comment: rather than latexmk, run `pdflatex` on the test file (with `\thanks`)  and show the full log that you get.

Comment: Note you can ignore the error in the title. The problem is (always) the first error. Latex is not expecting to fail on the TS1 encoding and can not really recover well, after that if you try to scroll past the error tex will try to recover but basically you get spurious errors and eventually some kind of loop that exceeeds this depth count so get the error you show.